# (laravel) Query builder using model of variable name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to insert into a table using its laravel model class, but I need to be able to insert into the table indicated by a variable. How can this be done? I tried the vanilla PHP moethod and the laravel facade method but both gave me errors:

```
$modelName = "model";

# this works no problem:
$model = new model();

# this blows up:
$model = new $modelName();

# this blows up:
$model::create($request->all());
```

the error given by laravel:

```
FatalThrowableError in Controller.php line 44:
Class 'model' not found
```

Comment: `$model = new $modelName();` forgot to instantiate it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for catching that. I updated the question, but the error didn't change.

Comment: how about `$modelName = model::class`?

Comment: @Burak good idea, but looks like the error remains :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must put the fully qualified class name:

> One must use the fully qualified name (class name with namespace
>   prefix).

```
$modelName = "App\\User"; // assuming User is located in the App namespace
$model = new $modelName();
```

You can learn more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php).

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I guess including the class path always has to be explicit in this case even when the class has been included?

Comment: also, why is it a backslash here instead of a foward slash?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the link to related part of the PHP documentation. 1) Yes, it seems so. 2) It is the one used by PHP, right? :)